# Is there much performance gain from using as few CSS classes as possible?

Tags: css, mobile-website

Recently I've come upon a mobile UI kit which used very long CSS class names, seemingly instead of utilizing multiple class names and CSS inheritance (e.g. `".container-element-subelement"`). Is there much performance gain from this? Because it sounds like a nightmare to have to maintain those stylesheets later.

Comment: Can you post some code examples from the mobile UI kit?

Comment: Sure. There are quite a few examples here: https://github.com/blackberry/bbUI.js/blob/master/src/bbUI.css

Comment: Some people like maintenance nightmares.  It looks like they're following this (in my opinion, moronic) pattern:  http://smacss.com/ (specifically:  http://smacss.com/book/type-module)

Comment: "seemingly instead of utilizing multiple class names and CSS inheritance" Do you have anyhing to back this up?

Comment: @cimmanon: Why is the reading in the link a bad approach? Sounds like they're keeping things fairly modular.

Comment: The only issue I see with the SMACSS approach is that there no 'subclassing' happening at all, since CSS doesn't support inheritance. It's more of a mixin with certain properties overridden.

Comment: SMACSS violates the DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself) principle in its naming conventions:  `.foo`, `.foo-bar`, `.foo-bar-baz`.  There's nothing wrong with modularity, just the way SMACSS suggests going about it.

Comment: Oh I see. Yes, that seems redundant, especially since selectors are parsed right to left and there is seemingly no advantage for the wordy class names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Performance gain from what you referred to should be negligible (of course, depends on the user's hardware, the page size, and browser).

There was some discussion on this here: [CSS child selector performance vs. class bloat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14013585/css-child-selector-performance-vs-class-bloat)

Comment: Great link. Seems like the best I can do is write good selectors. Properly written CSS should be fast enough, but the gains in maintainability will be far greater compared to the performance gain/maintainability ratio of using unwieldy class names. I figured as much.

Answer (score 1):

Well the answer is YES it will affect performance.

If you use a .css framework just for a little option (like loading all jquery-ui, just to make rounded corner on a single div, ... non-sence.

also, take it more deeply, comparing :
    .this-verry-long-way-too-long-css-selector-to-do-something {}
and
    .thisselector {}

- 45 caracters difference = many bytes difference,
- multiply by numbers of too-long-selector-names,
- multiply by number of times your .css file is sended by your server
  **= bandwidth**

There is that tool you can use : **yslow** 'firefox plugin' to help you study and tweek .css performance

EDIT : ok, i understand your question.
Then, it's a DOM engine relevant and good question.

So, *i think* a DOM engine will perform better if stacking basic simple selectors.

You can use Chrome Developer Tools' Selector Profiler (in the Profiles panel) to profile the time it takes a browser to process selectors in your page (match + apply styles to the matching elements.)

There a documentation here : http://moduscreate.com/efficient-dom-and-css/

carry on

Comment: I was more specifically asking whether either of the two scenarios will have much of a considerable performance difference: `.class .subclass .subsubclass` and `.class-subclass-subsubclass`.