# When do I use class/id and when do I target the html tag directly

Tags: html, css, web

I have (another) question concerning html/css best practices. I checked the web and this site but all that came up where articles on when to use IDs and when to use classes. However, that's not what I am struggling with.

I would like to know when to use class selectors over html element selectors and vice versa.

Example:

HTML

```
<div class="container">
    <p class="nested-p">feefifem</p>
</div>
```

CSS option 1:

```
.nested-p{...}
```

CSS option 2:

```
.container p{...}
```

Which option is preferable under which circumstances and why?

Comment: This might also be of interest to you: [CSS child selector performance vs. class bloat](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14013585/css-child-selector-performance-vs-class-bloat)

Comment: "Best practices" questions are not really appropriate for SO.  You already know your A and B, so do a benchmark and see what works best for you.

Answer (score 7):

The first option is for All the `.nested-p` classes ( you can put this class to the `html ,body , p ,div and aside etc` --- well  - to anything you want.)

The second one is for all `p` under `.container` ( yeah , that's right , only `p`)

Regarding priority - the second one is higher ([**read this**](http://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/) )

why ?

Becuase of this :

[image]

A few pasted drawing (just to emphasize)

[image]

So the second one will look like this :

[image]

while the first one will look like:

[image]

Comment: but if you put .container p above .nested-p in the css it will still take precedence as witnessed by the following jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/KVVcF/

Comment: `.container p` has a specificity of [0 0 1 1] but `.nested-p` has a specificity of [0 0 1 0] so therefore `.container p` takes precedence.

Comment: @Charles380 correct. edited. ( confused between first and second

Comment: Although if you are creating classes just to work around specificity problems then there's a larger problem at hand.

Comment: Very cool image and examples.

Answer (score 2):

As metioned, style precedence is ordered by specificity. Here's a simple demo to illustrate.

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
    <p class="nested-p">Something</p>
</div>

<div class="container">
    <p class="nested-p2">Something</p>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.nested-p {
    background: red; /* yeah right, this isn't going to be applied */
}

/* more specific */
.container .nested-p2 {
    background: green;

}

/* less specific */
.container p {
    font-size: 2em; /* will be applied to both nested p*/
    background: blue; /* only applied to the first because it is less specific than the previous declaration */
}

/* even less specific */
.nested-p2 {
    background: blue; /* will not be applied */
    font-size: 4em; /* will be applied, because it's not applied in the more specific class */
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/brbcoding/m44ck/)

Answer (score 0):

class selectors are used to apply a specific property to number of dom elements

Example:

```
<li Class="color">home</li>

<li Class="color">about us</li>

<li Class="color">career</li>

<li Class="color">contact</li>
```

in css you can write :

```
.color{
the properties u wish to apply for all
}
```

And second scenorio is

```
    <div class="saikiran">

    <p > jsdbkabd</p>
    <p >aksdkd</p>

<ul>

<li>list1</li>

<li>list2</li>

<li>list3</li>

<li>list4</li>

</ul>
</div>
```

if u want first two paragraphs a particular style you can go with

```
.saikiran p{style u wish here}
```

hope it helped you!!! happy coding

Comment: I think OP was more concerned with selector specificity. They explained that they knew how to use classes in the post.